# When should one normalise the data and when should one standardize the data as a part of data pre-processing while building ML models?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, normalization, standardization, data-preprocessing

I have seen people using both normalisation which is min-max normalization ( all values will be between 0,1) and standardize( normal distribution) the data as part of pre-processing.
It's given that if data is skewed prefer normalization. What if there are one hot encoded values in other variables in a regression analysis? then also should we prefer normalization( as unit of different variables would be same) .

Can someone tell the exhaustive conditions of when to use which data transformation techniques?